# Find temperature occurrence (height) between two temperatures at specific heights from ground

Tags: c#, interpolation, temperature, altitude

Hi I am trying to interpolate temperature height from ground.

Knowing the following information tempA, heightA, tempB, heightB, I need to find where targetedTemperature occurs.

```
 public static double TemperatureHeight(
            double heightA, double tempA,
            double heightB, double tempB,
            int targetTemperature)
        {
            //heightA = 4322.76; //height in Meters from ground
            //heightB = 4989.064; //height in Meters from gound
            //tempA = -9.9; // Temperature in celcius at heightA
            //tempB = 13.6; // Temperature in celcius at height B
            //targetTemperature = -10; //At what height from ground, this temperature exists?


            //This is temporary solution, to pick closest height. Ideally I would like to know at what height (in meters) does targetTemperature exists.
            if (targetTemperature - tempA > targetTemperature - tempB)
                return heightB;
            return heightA;
        }
```

I found similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25882161/942855 but not exactly what I need.

Comment: What's the problem?  Have you tried linear interpolation?  What part of this do you need help with?  What went wrong with what you tried?  What do you expect as results?

Comment: Thanks this looks like working for what I need https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838328/942855. Will validate it further and comment if there is any discrepancy